# C++ program doesn't run correctly

Tags: c++, struct, codeblocks

I have written a note program. Which reads some notes, keeps them and allows the user to delete, select or update a note. It's compiling and running, but it doesn't run correctly.

I have this struct:

```
struct List {
    char title[101];
    char text[501];
    int cont;
    struct List* next;

};typedef List list;
```

And these functions:

```
List* insert (List *l, char ti[101], char te[501]) {
    List* new = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy (new -> title, ti);
    strcpy (new -> text, te);
    new -> next = l;
    new -> cont = id;
    id++;
    return (new);
}

List* delete (List* l, int v) {
   List *ant = NULL;
   List *p = l;

   while (p != NULL && p -> cont != v) {
      ant = p;
      p = p -> next;
   }
   if (p == NULL)
      return l;
   if (ant == NULL)
      l = p -> next;
   else
        ant -> next = p -> next;
   free(p);
   return l;
}

void print (List *l) {
    List *p;
    for (p = l; p != NULL; p = p -> next){
      cout << "\nTitle: " << p -> title << "\n";
      cout << "Text: " << p -> text <<  "\n";
      cout << "Code: " << p -> cont << "\n" << "\n";
    }
}
```

On the `int main` I have inserted and printed a couple of times and it worked fine. But when I want delete a note, it doesn't delete nor do get an error code. Yesterday it was working fine, but today when i got to test it, nothing works right. I can't understand why it was working and now it stopped.

As requested, the main program:

```
List* ini(){
    return (NULL);
}


int main() {
        List *l;
        char title[101];
        char text[501];
        char v;

        List* L1 = ini();

        cout << "\nTitle: ";
        gets(title);
        cout << "Text: ";
        gets(text);
        L1 = insert (L1,title,text);

        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\nTitle: ";
        gets(title);
        cout << "Text: ";
        gets(text);
        L1 = insert (L1,title,text);

        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\nTitle: ";
        gets(title);
        cout << "Text: ";
        gets(text);
        L1 = insert (L1,title,text);

        print(L1);

        cout << "Delete: ";
        cin >> v;
        L1 = delete(L1, v);

        print(L1);

        return(0);

        }
```

Comment: Please show an example of what your code is doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using new as a variable name in a c++ program? Also why are you using malloc instead of new in a c++ program?

Comment: it just don't delete the notes, if i insert one note and call the delete for the note that i insert, and print the results, i still have that one note on my list.

Comment: Show the code that calls `delete`. I suspect you're not saving the return value.

Comment: May I recommend you to post your code to codereview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) If you do say I'll be happy to comment on some things. There seem to be couple of concepts you havent really got the hang off yet

Comment: I think you are compiling with C language, not C++. Otherwise it doesn't compile.

Comment: @drescherjm is a pretty tough translation from Portuguese to English, in Portuguese we use "prox" which would be next to English.

Comment: @LPs I thought that but then there is cout.

Comment: Some Tips: 1. Don't use keywords for variable or function names. 2. Don't use `malloc` and `free` but `new[]` / `delete[]`. 3. Don't use character arrays but `std::string`. 4. Show the calling code, the resulting output and the desired output. (And perhaps explain why you expect certain output).

Comment: @drescherjm ..but c++ allow to name a variable with keywords like "new"? Really?

Comment: @Pixelchemist, the names are just a raw translation, for me i call them "prox" and "retira", it is a work for college and i'm strictly prohibited to use string.

Comment: Ah - ok - you've translated them into C++ keywords which is confusing :)

Comment: Anyway - it works, I just tried it - even if it could use a good polish with a C++ style guide.  You'd better show the contents of main() as well in the question...

Comment: @laurisvr Might be important to note that the code **has to run correctly** *before* being posted to Code Review

Comment: @Simon, okay my bad. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @OliviaThebaldiGarcia My goodness, you're using `gets`?   And get your money back (if you paid for this course) -- you are not being taught C++.

Comment: @OliviaThebaldiGarcia Also, this code does not compile due to using `new` as a variable name.  This is not valid C++ at all.  What compiler are you using that allows you to use C++ keywords as variables?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is for college, the teacher only threw work for us to do and have to do with what we know :/ we are just on the third period, or the third semester.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie as i sad before, the names are just a raw translation, i'm brazilian so for me i call them "prox", "retira" and so

Comment: @OliviaThebaldiGarcia Please don't do raw translations, just post the code as-is.  We are looking at your code, there is no need for others to try and decipher it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, i'll do it the next time, is my second post here so i'm still getting the terms and rules.

Comment: @OliviaThebaldiGarcia `L1 = (L1, v);`  Explain what that line in `main` is supposed to do.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, while editing i forgot to call the function, now its fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: I rewrote your code to not do translations, so that now `delete` is a valid function called `deleteItem`.**

Your immediate issue is this:

```
char v;
//...
cin >> v;
L1 = deleteItem(L1, v);  // <-- v is a char,
```

but

```
List* deleteItem (List* l, int v) {
```

You are passing a `char` variable to `deleteItem` when you should be passing an int.  Change the type of `v` to `int`.

What is happening is that your `char` is being translated to an int.  So if you enter `1`, that is being sent as 49, since the ASCII value of `1` is 49.

One of things that C++ allows you to do is declare variables close to their point of use.  If you had declared `v` closer to the `deleteItem` function call, you may have spotted the mistake yourself.

Comment: omg, how i didn't notice it before, it was a test for another function and i forgot to change it back, thank you so much, now it work fine :D